# "working fine" vs "working properly"

Tags: word-usage, differences, idioms

These two phrases have been widely used by my mates and me:

> My computer is working fine.
>
> My computer doesn't work properly.

However, for some weird reason, it seems to me like these phrases are just wrong but I cannot say why:

> My computer is not working fine.
>
> My computer doesn't work fine.
>
> My computer works properly.
>
> My computer is working properly.

Some thoughts about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, they are all correct, but depending on the context in which you use them, they may sound "off."

"My computer is not working fine" would usually be a retort like:

> "Your computer seems to be working fine."
>
> "No, my computer is *not* working fine."

If you're just stating that your computer is not working fine then you would maybe say:

> "My computer isn't working so fine."

or simply:

> "My computer isn't working."

It doesn't sound right because nobody speaks like that, but just because we don't speak like that doesn't mean the facts behind the grammar aren't true.